# Best way to write Scala methods signature dealing with exceptions

Tags: api, scala, exception, scalaz, scalaz7

In order to handle exceptions in Scala, I prefer avoiding basic `try`/`catch` and benefit from functional thinking with `Validation` from Scalaz (similar to `Either` type in certain cases).

My application exposes some services. Imagine this method (making no real sense, but good for the concept) in my service layer. It associates a `Buyer` (purchaser) with his new `Car` and returns the `Car` containing this association if all rules are passed with success:

```
def create(carDTO: CarDTO, buyerDTO: BuyerDTO): Validation[Either[TechnicalFailure, List[CarCreationFailure]], CarDTO]
```

Explanation:  Creating a `Car` may lead to one of both exceptions types:

- **Technical failures** (when databases crashes for instance) wrapping `Throwable` exceptions.
- **Business failures** (custom application's rules preventing from inconsistence, for instance, a `Car` with an illegal status). `CarCreationFailure` is one and of course could be extended by more `precised` failure.

My question is especially focus on client side and deals specifically with more than one potential `Business Failure`.

Should the return type `Validation[Either[TechnicalFailure, List[CarCreationFailure]], CarDTO]` be replaced by the less cumbersome: `ValidationNel[Throwable, CarDTO]`

Note here `ValidationNel` (accumulating errors/exceptions into a `NonEmptyList`).

A drawback would be that a new reader couldn't, at first glance, guess that this method returns either `TechnicalFailure` or `CarCreationFailure` (subclass of `BusinessFailure` so); just a too frightening `Throwable`.

He'd be forced to apply a pattern matching on every `Throwable` types contained within my application to in order to be sure to not forget anyone... => messy.

What is the cleanest way among those solutions, or maybe...other one?

Comment: This is more like a "code review" question than SO question.  Anyway, why not create a supertrait for both `TechnicalFailure` and `CarCreationFailures` (which would wrap `List[CarCreationFailure]`)?  Then your type system knows what can come back and you can pattern match to deal with the cases (and you can stick everything in a `Validation`).

Comment: You almost _certainly_ do not want to catch all of `Throwable` unless you're writing something like a servlet container. Look at the `Error` half of `Throwable` an ask yourself whether you really want to (and can) handle all of them.

Comment: Agree with @RexKerr, this question is rather general and it's hard to give a specific answer. Certainly I would think about changing your first propesed result type to `ValidationNel[Either[TechnicalFailure, CarCreationFailure], CarDTO]`.

Comment: @Randall Schulz Actually, one client of my service is a `Controller` like any Servlet for instance. I don't want to swallow `Error` or `Runtime` happened at server side since I expect `Controllers` to act accordingly following my custom rules, and not basic ones provided by any container or any frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like these, I personally use a custom class called `Tri` which works like both `Try` and `Either`:

```
sealed trait Tri [+Value, +Problem] { ... }
final case class Good[+Value](v: Value) extends Tri[Value, Nothing] { ... }
final case class Bad[+Problem](p: Problem) extends Tri[Nothing, Problem] { ... }
final case class Ugly(th: Throwable) extends Tri[Nothing, Nothing] { ... }
```

with appropriate methods to handle the most common operations one wants. In this case, I'd simply return to the client

```
Tri[CarDTO, List[CarCreationFailure]]
```

and have the exceptions wrapped into a custom exception class as needed.  This both is up-front about what may or may not happen when the code itself is working normally, and leaves unstated--as usual--exceptional conditions that need to be handled sooner or later, including things like database errors.  Then you just e.g.:

```
create(car, buyer) match {
  case Good(dto) => // Yay
  case Bad(xs) =>   // Handle list of car creation failures
  case Ugly(th) =>  // Handle exceptions
}
```

I am not aware of any similar functionality in Scalaz7, though you can build the pieces (as you have, though why not use `\/`?) more easily than in Scalazless Scala, so you might be less motivated to create  this kind of tripartite error handling class.

Comment: Actually, with this solution, you simulate an `Either` concept focused on 3 elements, rather than the basic `Right`and `Left` =>  Why not :). Besides, what is the meaning of `\/` you have suggested?  Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I've just seen look at the source code, `\/` acts as a "disjunction.

Comment: Finally, I prefer following your solution in comment: wrapping `TechnicalFailure` and `CreationalFailures` into a parent `trait` and still benefit of Scalaz7's `Validation`. May you provide a little sample with the famous `\/` in order to, maybe, improve my solution? Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: @Mik378 - I don't really use Scalaz since it mostly solves problems that I don't have much trouble solving myself, and makes more difficult things I already find difficult.  (Not a general indictment of Scalaz, by the way--it just doesn't suit me personally, given what I'm doing now.)  So I'm not confident my example would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

We use something similar (simpler and less elegant) to what Rex Kerr uses.

All business exceptions/errors are wrapped in a custom `BusinessException`, all other errors are throwing exceptions of various kind.

We use the basic `Try` and a servlet will have code looking like (much simplified)

```
    ( req getParameter "action" match {

        case null          ⇒ Failure( new BusinessException( "Missing required parameter 'action'" ) )
        case "doThis"  ⇒ doThis()
        case "doThat"  ⇒ doThat( req )
        case x         ⇒ Failure( new BusinessException( "Uknown Action '" + x + "'" ) )
    } ) match {

        case Success( someResponse ) ⇒ //send 200 with some response
        case Failure(t) if t.isInstanceOf[BusinessException] => //send 400 with exception message 
        case Failure( t )        ⇒ //send 500 with exception message
    }
```

Methods like `doThis`have signatures of the type

```
def doThis(): Try[ Option[ String ] ] = Try {
    //do stuff
}
```

The advantage of this simple mechanism is that it is easy to wrap existing Java code throwing exceptions, which is our use case.